# 'Create Table' sometimes fails in PHPUnit Database query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My issue is, that two identical queries for creating a table give different results.
/classes/database.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: Timon
 * Date: 10/12/18
 * Time: 3:10 PM
 */

namespace canvas\classes;
use \PDO;

class Database
{
    private $connction;

    public function __construct($configuration = [])
    {
        include 'values.php';
        $this->connction = $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db, $user, $passwd);
    }

    public function query($query)
    {
        return $this->connction->query($query);
    }
}
$database = new Database();
```

Now the test unit:
/Test/databaseTest.php

```
<?php

namespace canvas\classes;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;


class DatabaseTest extends TestCase
{

    /**
     * @param string $query
     *
     * @dataProvider providerTestQuery
     */
    public function testQuery($query){
        $database= new Database();
        var_dump($query);
        $result=$database->query($query);
        var_dump($result);
        self::assertNotFalse($result);
    }
    public function providerTestQuery()
    {
        return array(
            array('Create Database Test'),
            array('Use Test'),
            array("CREATE TABLE employees (
            id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
            firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            email VARCHAR(50)
            )"),
        );
    }
    public function testCreateTable(){
        $database= new Database();
        var_dump($database->query('Use Test'));
        self::assertNotFalse($database->query("CREATE TABLE persons(
        id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        first_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        last_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        email VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL UNIQUE
    )"));
    }
}
```

The test of testQuery with the last data set is failing, but  testCreateTable is success.
If I write my queries by hand, it will fail, if I copy it from the internet, it may or may not be a success.
PS: I am currently using an idea from JetBrains. Might it be the formatting? The queries are valid in my database SQL executer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first Create Table went into a different database and didn't get deleted. Therefore it failed, because the table already existed.